# Java Spring boot

Tags: java, spring

При попытке компиляции Spring приложения возникает ошибка. Понятия не имею, что с этим делать, много тем посмотрел, но ответа так и не нашел, буду благодарен за помощь!

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.4.1:run (default-cli) on project sitespring: Application finished with exit code: 1 -> [Help 1]
```

Apache maven 3.6.3 version, java 1.8.0_261

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.labwork</groupId>
    <artifactId>sitespring</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>sitespring</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>


    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Основной файл

```
package com.labwork.sitespring;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class RunApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(RunApp.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Попробуйте тут посмотреть: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60411383/failed-to-execute-goal-org-springframework-bootspring-boot-maven-plugin2-1-3-r

Comment: Всё та же ошибка

Comment: Скорей всего не прогрузились зависимости, попробуйте их обновить, ну или попробуйте выполнить `mvn clean install` которая должна подтянуть изменения и собрать проект. Или вы как то не правильно запускаете проект.
С кодом если что все точно ок, тк проверил и у меня все запустилось.